# Group values into an "others bucket"

Tags: excel, charts

I have a list (30+) of users with the number of times those users were active per month in my system. I'm using an Excel chart to show which users have been consistently active over time. About one third of the users come consistently (several times a month) while others come one month and not another.

Unfortunately since I have 30+ users, the colors in the Excel chart are difficult to distinguish from one another. What I was thinking to remedy this was to only show the top 10 (or 15) users and group the others into an "others" or "catch-all" bucket and still shows it in the chart.

A sample image of the chart:

[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_dh4cDXmimmZXA0X2IwOGJGSDA/edit?usp=sharing]

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: do you have a data that you can share? Also what type of chart are you using?

Comment: Do you have Excel 2010 or later? A slicer or filter is a possibility.

Comment: Hi @cronos2546, I indeed have 2010 (professional plus).

Comment: @KashifQureshi, I would have to change/obfuscate the name of the users because of the sensitivity of the data; well mostly because of my company very strict policy when it comes to sharing that information with the outside world. That said it should be easy to share the chart. Let me do this

Comment: @KashifQureshi, check out a sample of the chart here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_dh4cDXmimmZXA0X2IwOGJGSDA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: OK @jeromeso I'm at work but will try to come up with a solution this afternoon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column that differentiates 'Active' from 'Non-active'. In the sample I had to create *overall* B and C were the most active so I populated D2 down with:

```
=IF(OR(B2="B",B2="C"),"Active","Non-active")
```

Adjust the formula if that distinction is made on a month by month basis. Create a Stacked Column PivotChart and in the PivotTable move the 'Active' together as necessary. Select each of the `Non-active` series (here only two for illustration) in the chart and apply the same colour fill to all.

[image: SO25674303 example]